# Nested each loops over array in Svelte - how to set unique id / key?

Tags: arrays, foreach, each, svelte, svelte-3

I would like to render an array in Svelte with the following form with two nested each loops.

```
const arr = [
    [ a, b, c ],
    [ d, e, f ],
    [ g, h, i ]
]

{#each arr as row, rowIndex}
    <div class="row">
        {#each row as cell, cellIndex ($arr[rowIndex][cellIndex]) }
            <div class="cell"> {cell} </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/each}
```

**Demo REPL** -> https://svelte.dev/repl/4dbec2d8c2ac4b6493e78418bd861f4c?version=3.38.2

Wanted effect => clicked element vanishes first, then elements to the right move over

When setting `{#each arr as row, rowIndex (rowIndex)}` + `{#each row as cell, cellIndex (cellIndex)}` it doesn't behave like that (-> https://svelte.dev/repl/e7369788e2614bbbbf9c42cde6a4130a?version=3.38.2)

In case the content of each cell is unique, setting the id on the cell like this works fine ->
`($arr[rowIndex][cellIndex])`

But if two cells contain the same content, that's not working. (Activate last element in arr in REPL store -> 'Cannot have duplicate keys in a keyed each')

So I am wondering if there is any way to set a unique id in this case on a different way?

I came up with some approaches to combine the rowIndex with the cellIndex e.g. like '00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, ...' but nothing of these worked:

```
rowIndex.toString().concat(cellIndex.toString())
""+rowIndex+cellIndex
+(""+rowIndex+cellIndex)
$arr[rowIndex][cellIndex]+rowIndex+cellIndex
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `cellIndex` as key in the inner `#each` instead of `$arr[rowIndex][cellIndex]`? This works because the key only needs to be unique within one particular `#each` which every nested `#each` ends up being.

Comment: You mean like this? `{#each row as cell , cellIndex (cellIndex)}` That doesn't have the desired effect neither - see this REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/e7369788e2614bbbbf9c42cde6a4130a?version=3.38.2 -> The clicked element should vanish and the elements to the right should move left afterwards. Like achieved in the first version (only working with unique cell contents) -> https://svelte.dev/repl/50c0e634709f4ea298420b6076e34546?version=3.38.2

Comment: You could add an id that stays the same for each cell to `arr` no matter the position after removal. So the id could be the initial cell index inside its row. The cells might then be objects like `{ color: "#FFFFFF", index: 0}`. You could then use this index property as key.

Comment: Could have been a solution, if the creation of the 'object-arr' could have been done via a derived store containing the id-content-objects, but still not the desired effect -> https://svelte.dev/repl/50c0e634709f4ea298420b6076e34546?version=3.38.2 (I assume it's because the derivedArr is rendered but the deletion happens on the 'basic' arr)

Comment: Exactly. I first thought of derived as well but it cannot work. But you can add the index to the original items.

Comment: Yes, when modifying the original items (or an 'unlinked' copy of the original array) it works https://svelte.dev/repl/d1b0f121b3354dee8e93fd22a83bdb13?version=3.38.2 but thats not really solving the problem, since there is no connection to the original array anymore and the reactivity is lost

Comment: What I meant is really to add it to the original array.

Comment: Ok, sure, if the data would be coming in in that format, the problem would be solved. Not sure yet, if it's possible for me to influence that, so still looking for a way to work directly on an array with the given format in the question.